# git rebase on other branch

Tags: git, integration, rebase, git-rebase

given the following scenario:

- We develop features on different topic branches.
- Before the release we merge all the topic-branches into `master`. The continuous integration then starts on that branch
- Additionally we also make small changes (typos etc...) directly on the master branch
- If everything works fine we merge all the changes from the master branch into the relase branch. This release branch will then be shipped

This workflow is fine as long as there is nothing wrong with our tests. But as soon as we decide not to ship a feature from master we run into troubles.

For example:

- We have 5 topic branches for different features
- We merge them all into `master`
- In addition to that, we have 2 separate commits directly on master (we fixed some typos)
- Now we find out, that 1 of the 5 features is not working as expected, we cannot ship it
- We still want to ship the other 4 features (+ the 2 commits directly made on master)

The only option we have now is:
 - merge the 4 topic branches directly into release
 - cherry pick the 2 commits on master into release

This can be rather annoying especially when we do not keep track of the commits made directly on master and the number increases.

I would like to have a scenario where we are able to:

- see all the commits (or better: merged branches)
- discard all the changes that we do not want to have in the next release
- merge all other changes into release

I already did some research and ran into `git rebase`. The `git rebase --interactive` came pretty close to what I expected.

The best scenario would be:

- rebase all changes from master to release interactively
- remove all commits (or better branches) that I don't need
- release has only the changes I want to

The problem however is:

When I do:

```
git checkout master
git rebase --interactive release
<changes>
```

I end up modifying the master branch and not the release branch. Adding the `--onto release` option doesn't help either.

Is there a possibility to commit the results of rebase on another branch?

regards
Leif

Comment: Can you give a more concrete example? Your scenario is confusing.

Comment: I changed the wording a little bit and added an example, hope it is more understandable

Comment: Shouldn't you do it reversely? `git chechout release` `git rebase -i master` ...

Comment: I tried that as well and it resulted in a noop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding of the problem is that you merge 5 different branches into master, and then, before merging into release, you realize one of the 5 has errors so you only want to keep the other 4.

With this being the case, why don't you `git revert` the merge commit of the faulty branch and move on with the rest? Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

For future reference, take a look at [Revert a faulty merge](http://schacon.github.com/git/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt), which explains some scenarios for "undoing" a merge. Also, see warnings in the Git `rebase` manual [Recovering From Upstream Rebase](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-rebase.html#_recovering_from_upstream_rebase) and in [Pro Git - Rewriting History](http://progit.org/book/ch6-4.html). And if you haven't already, take a look at the [Git project's workflow](http://schacon.github.com/git/gitworkflows.html) and [A successful Git branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).

A better workflow in the future might be to merge feature branches onto a release branch and only merge the release branch onto `master` after it has passed testing, QA, user acceptance, etc. I usually wait to do this merge right before the release date. You can always do a test merge further before the release date to ensure there will not be any merge conflict surprises.

To fix your current situation, let's say we have the following history with two fix commits and five feature branch merge commits:

```
$ git --no-pager log --oneline --decorate --all --graph
*   e202262 (HEAD, master) Merge branch 'f5'
|\  
| * d9930ca (f5) f5
* |   f9d743b Merge branch 'f4'
|\ \  
| * | eea7737 (f4) f4
| |/  
* |   c84ad9f Merge branch 'f3'
|\ \  
| * | 135c7f7 (f3) f3
| |/  
* |   65ed393 Merge branch 'f2'
|\ \  
| * | 9a9b5b6 (f2) f2
| |/  
* |   76ae0e8 Merge branch 'f1'
|\ \  
| * | 8a02982 (f1) f1
| |/  
* | ace81a9 fix 2
* | d4b32e1 fix 1
|/  
* ab6d5b0 A
```

What I would do is:

1. `reset` `master` to the `ab6d5b0` commit.
2. Create a `release` branch.
3. Add the `fix 1` and `fix 2` commits to the release branch.
4. Assuming `f2` is the problematic feature, merge the `f1`, `f3`, `f4` and `f5` branches onto the `release` branch.
5. While testing is underway, do a dry run merge of `release` onto `master`.
6. If all is good, merge `release` onto `master`.

Here are the commands that would be executed, using the above history, to accomplish these steps (see the [Git reference manual](http://schacon.github.com/git/git.html) for further information about these commands):

```
# Reset master to before the fix and merge commits
git checkout master
git reset --hard ab6d5b0
# Create a release branch
git checkout -b release
# Add the fix commits back
git cherry-pick d4b32e1
git cherry-pick ace81a9
# Merge feature branches
git merge f1
git merge f3
git merge f4
git merge f5
# Dry run merge
git checkout master
git merge --no-ff --no-commit release
git reset --hard HEAD
# Merge release to master
git checkout master
git merge --no-ff release
```

This will leave you with the following history:

```
$ git --no-pager log --oneline --decorate --all --graph
*   e24c16e (HEAD, master) Merge branch 'release'
|\  
| *   d23369a (release) Merge branch 'f5' into release
| |\  
| | * d9930ca (f5) f5
| |/  
|/|   
| *   8b90602 Merge branch 'f4' into release
| |\  
| | * eea7737 (f4) f4
| |/  
|/|   
| *   926c094 Merge branch 'f3' into release
| |\  
| | * 135c7f7 (f3) f3
| |/  
|/|   
| *   e964e13 Merge branch 'f1' into release
| |\  
| | * 8a02982 (f1) f1
| |/  
|/|   
| * bb5f6f5 fix 2
| * e8ffeef fix 1
|/  
| * 9a9b5b6 (f2) f2
|/  
* ab6d5b0 A
```

Since release preparation is done on a separate branch, `master` remains clean and release management headaches due to feature selection issues may be mitigated.